# Hook when new CPT published AND postmeta inserted

Tags: hooks

I would like to know if there is a hook that fires when a new CPT is published and its postmeta has been inserted.

I was using publish_mycpt but found that the postmeta wasn't being saved at that point. I would like my hook to run only for this custom post type, not for all posts.

The function I will be calling via the action hook is also used by a scheduled cron job, so it's not only called when a new post is published via the administration interface, not sure if this is important or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can do it using the save_post hook, than do a conditional check for the post's post-type and the value of its post meta.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'do_some_function');
function do_some_function($post_id) {
    global $post;
    $post_type_as_taxonomy = array('cpt-1','cpt-2'); // this is your hooked custom post types
    $post = get_post( $post_id );
    if(in_array($post->post_type, $post_type_as_taxonomy) && $post->post_status=='publish'){ // check if the post is hooked & published
        $my_meta = get_post_meta($post_id, 'my-meta', true); // check if  it has a post meta with the ket 'my-meta'
        if($my_meta){
            // do your hook function here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works with a small modification, 'wp_insert_post' instead of 'save_post'. Not sure why that is so, I thought the two hooks were the same.

Comment: Another question to help me understand what's happening here, since the action passes both the post id and the post itself `do_action('wp_insert_post', $post_id, $post);` would I also be able to call the function like so: `function do_some_function($post)` instead of using the $post_id parameter?

Comment: That is interesting. Never though it would work using 'wp_insert_post'. You can 'print_f($post) inside the 'do_some_function' than do a 'wp_die()' to find out what is inside the $post.